# How to extract the summary value text $39 from the html provided through Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

HTML is as follows:

```
<h3 data-testid="cartSubTotalAmt" class="inline bottom-offset-0 pull-right ng-binding">$39.00</h3>
```

[image]

I need to fetch the total summary value $39.00.
Kindly help me to locate and fetch the value.

Comment: share the HTML code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to extract the text of the *total summary value* i.e. **$39.00** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("h3[data-testid='cartSubTotalAmt']"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//h3[@data-testid='cartSubTotalAmt']"))).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  ```